# Network Policy Ingress is not working after sidecar injection

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kubernetes-networkpolicy

**Bug description**

I am trying a network policy example to allow the traffic from specific namespace. Everything works good until I inject a sidecar for nginx application then all calls are blocked.
[This](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes/blob/master/06-allow-traffic-from-a-namespace.md) is the example I am trying to implement.

**Expected behavior**

Whether its sidecar is injected or not, when a call is coming from whitelisted namespace, it shouldn't block it.

**Steps to reproduce the bug**

Simple go through [this](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes/blob/master/06-allow-traffic-from-a-namespace.md) example, just inject nginx application with the istio's side car.

**Version (include the output of `istioctl version --remote` and `kubectl version`)**

Kubernetes: 1.13.10

Istio: 1.1.10

Please help me understand what should I need to do to make it work or do I have to add something else in Network Policy for istio-injection?

P.S
Although it works, when I allow traffic from all the namespaces even after sidecar injection

```
ingress:
- {}
```

Comment: Hi, in your scenario, are all three namespaces istio-injected? Do you have only one policy in place `kubectl get networkpolicy`?

Comment: @yyyyahir no only `web` is injected and yeah only one network policy in `web` namespace.

Comment: I replicated it, injecting only the `default` namespace in which the Nginx service is running and blocking all namespaces except from `prod`. It worked correctly using *K8s 1.13.7*, *Istio 1.2.2* with *Calico* as implementation for network policy. Either there is an extra configuration pushed into Istio or there is another network policy overlapping with this one. I'd suggest start from zero and retry keeping only this policy.